# BASH - Pattern Matching Issue

Tags: regex, bash, pattern-matching

I'm having an issue with pattern matching. I know the solution to this should be relatively simple but I'm stuck. Lets say

```
for something in ${OPTARG[@]} ; do
[[ ${path} =~ "J"${something} ]]
```

In this case, I want OPTARG = 1

When I run this it returns all matches to 1 i.e. J112, J174 etc and I ONLY want it to return J1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use `$` that matches the end of the string:

```
[[ $path =~ J$something$ ]]
```